# How can I test for the detected language via Bing's Translation API to be equal to "EN"?

Tags: php, bing-api

```
$language = file_get_contents('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Detect?appid=APPID&text=hello');

$language = str_replace('"', '', $language);

if($language != 'en')
{
    echo 'not english';
}
{
    echo 'english';
}
```

So, what happens in the code above is `file_get_contents` will output `"en"`, I then remove the quotation marks and compare if it is equal to `en`. But the problem with the code above is that it will output `not english` even though `'en' != 'en'`.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I also tried to convert `$language` to a string `(string)$language`, but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump( $language )` before and after the `str_replace()`?

Comment: `string(7) ""en"" string(5) "en"`

Comment: What could the remaining 3 characters be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you're getting from Bing contains a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), or a byte order mark, which is invisible when echoed.

To remove the BOM, try this function:

```
function removeBOM($str = "") {
    if (substr($str, 0, 3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) {
        $str=substr($str, 3);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

So line 3 of your code would be:

```
$language = removeBOM(str_replace('"', '', $language));
```

Comment: You're welcome! I've gotten tons of good help from this site, so today I finally decided to create an account to try to give back a bit. :)